# How to check if object is instance of SocketIO.Socket or net.Socket in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using both generic sockets via the `net` import as well as sockets from socket.io, and I would like to make a function that works differently depending on which type of socket is passed.

However, the constructor names for both are just "Socket" so I cannot use `object.constructor.name`, and `object instanceof SocketIO.Socket` throws an error saying SocketIO is not defined.

Example:

```js
const net = require('net');
const io = require('socket.io')(httpsServer);

function test(socket) {
  if (socket instanceof net.Socket) // Do thing
  else if (socket instanceof SocketIO.Socket) // Do other thing
}
```

I have also tried using `io.Socket`, as well as `sIO.socket` with `const sIO = require('socket.io')`.  Is there any way to make this work by class checking, or do I need to do something like check for a property specific to only one type of socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using ["duck typing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) where you test what properties/methods exist.  The phrase duck typing comes from the notion that if it walks and talks like a duck, it must be a duck.

For example to see if a socket is a socket.io socket, you can look for socket.io specific methods and properties that would not be present on a different type of socket such as a `net.socket` socket.

Assuming this is server-side code, it is easiest to see if it is a socket.io socket and, if not, it must be your other choice:

```
// look for any one of several socket.io-unique properties
function isSocketIO(socket) {
    return !!(typeof socket.join === "function" || socket.rooms || socket.handshake);
}
```

Comment: Ah okay thank you, I didn't realize this was a standard practice - it always seemed a bit messy to me.  
  
I also was not aware of this truthiness concept (`!!`); would you mind explaining what the advantage of this is over doing just `return (typeof socket.join === "function" || socket.rooms || socket.handshake)`?

Comment: @epiqu1n - !! guarantees that it is returning a boolean.  Without that, it could return the values `socket.rooms` or `socket.handshake` which would probably be usable by the caller, just not as clean IMO.

Comment: I see, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You might check for the .constructor of given Object.

```
socket.constructor === net.Socket
```

Comment: That would work in my case since there is only one other type of socket (socket.io) that it could be, but I was hoping to understand the underlying problem in the event that there is more than one class that I am unable to directly check.

Comment: You can check for "socket.constructor === SocketIO.Socket" too. For an arbitrary amount of constructors. There are no classes in JavaScript. But you can check for prototypes and constructors. Even for the prototype's prototype etc.

Comment: That's the problem though.  With SocketIO in Node.js, the constructor `SocketIO.Socket` does not exist during runtime, even though that is the type of any sockets that are instantiated.